# Checking for roles in a discord bot error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I used this code to check for roles in my bot, but for some reason I get an error.

```
client.on("message", message => {
 if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "ROLE NAME")) return;
 // code...
});
```

The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `message.member` is `undefined`, you might want to check if this is done in a guild or not. If it is in a guild it will return the `member` property, while if it isn't, it won't. What you want to do is check if the message was sent from a guild or not, try the code below:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // `!` means `non-existent` or `is not`, and if the user sends the message from a guild  
  // this will not be triggered, since we know they are in, rather than not in, but, if
  // it was sent outside of a guild, say a DM, then it will return the command, not trigerring
  // any errors or such.
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // This will not allow this command to be triggered by the bot itself, since it may
  // return a loop.
  if (message.author === client.user) return;

  // If the author of the message is a bot, then return, since bots can be used to spam
  // and this will also spam your bot's API request. Webhooks work the same way.
  // `||` means `or` if you didn't know.
  if (message.author.bot || message.webhookID) return;

  // Checks if the member has the role "ROLE NAME", and if they do, return.
  if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "ROLE NAME")) return;
  // code...
});
```